# symfony2 and run service automatically

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, containers

i decided to create a service in symfony2.4 that can access me to the container in all of scopes in my project.

so i created a model:

```
namespace Nevec\RaxcidoBundle\Model;

class Base {
    public static $container;

    public function __construct() {
        self::$container = $container;
    }


}
```

and set this model as a service in resources/config/services.yml

```
parameters:
    nevec_raxcido.core: Nevec\RaxcidoBundle\Model\Base

services:
    nevec_raxcido.example:
        class: %nevec_raxcido.core%
        arguments: [@service_container]
```

now, as you know i should call this service in controllers like this:

```
$this->get("nevec_raxcido.example");
```

but i want to auto load this service, without call above command in controllers

the question is how can i automatically load a service after kernel boot in symfony2?

Comment: What do you want to reach? What's the goal of your service?

Comment: i want to access to the container and doctrine in custom models that i created in Model folder with this: $container = Model\Base::$container;

Comment: You are trying to make the service container a global object. This would lead you to many good practice breaks. Really - you don't need this..

Comment: You can inject the container into services you want. But the better approach is injecting specific services directly (instead of whole container).

Comment: ok, good idea, i just send doctrine to my service, but how can call service automatically? i dont want to call this in all of my controllers!!!

Comment: You just have to use symfony dependency injection

Comment: it was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179191/constructor-in-symfony2-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution, it seems that we should use listeners into services.yml like:

```
parameters:
    nevec_raxcido.core: Nevec\RaxcidoBundle\Model\Base

services:
    nevec_raxcido.example:
        class: %nevec_raxcido.core%
        arguments: [@service_container]
        tags:
            - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest}
```

and this model:

```
<?php
namespace Nevec\RaxcidoBundle\Model;

class Base{
    public static $container;

    public function __construct($container) {

        self::$container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest($event){
        return;
    }

}
```

so you can access to the container in all scopes of your application with this:

```
$container = Model\Base::$container;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please don't use the service container. Use dependency injection.

```
class Service {
    private $service;

    public function __construct(SomeServiceInterface $someService){
        $this -> service = $service;
    }
}
```

and the yml:

```
services:
    service1:
        class: SOMENAMESPACE\Service
        arguments: [@service2]
    service2:
        class: SOMENAMESPACE\SomeService
```

Now you can access SOMENAMESPACE\SomeService in SOMENAMESPACE\Service. And you can get the service in a controller via:

```
$this -> get('service1');
```

Let's say doctrine is your concrete service you want to inject.

Do this:

```
class Service {
    private $em;

    protected function getEm(ObjectManager $em){
        $this -> em = $em;
    }
}

services:
    service1:
        class: SOMENAMESPACE\Service
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

Second part of the question: How to autoload? Pretty easy. Build a "BaseController" and extend it.

```
class BaseAppController extends Controller{
    private $service;

    protected function getService(){
        if (!($this -> service instanceof SomeServiceInterface)) $this -> service = $this -> get('service');
        return $this -> service;
    }
}
```

access via $this -> getService()

Comment: The second part of your answer doesn't work this way ... `ContainerAware` classes like the ones extending `Controller` receive the service-container via **setter injection** (aka. a call to `setContainer(...)`  injects the container **after** the object has been created) ... `$this->get(..)` is **NOT** possible in the constructor of a ContainerAware class because it would try to access the `$this->container` property that is **NOT set** at this point yet!

Comment: ok never tried to do it. Thanks for your reply. What about the kernel.event.listener? It could point to a certain function. Has the container been built before?