# Symfony2 getUser() in Listener Class from Security Context failing although Token exists

Tags: php, symfony

Objective is to get the currently logged on user dumped to web profiler.

I have a listener class with the Container injected:

```
namespace Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\EventListener;

use Classes\geoPlugin;
use Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;

class CountryListener //extends FilterControllerEvent
{
    protected $_container;

    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->_container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $sess = $this->_container->get("session"); // Get the current session

        $user = $this->_container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

        dump($user); 
    }
}
```

With this as it stands when I visit the webpage it loads without any formatting and I receive the error 'An Error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (Internal Server Error: 500)

Do you want to open profiler?'

I click ok and receive this error: 'Error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object'

However if I have the code like so:

```
namespace Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\EventListener;

use Classes\geoPlugin;
use Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;

class CountryListener //extends FilterControllerEvent
{
    protected $_container;

    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->_container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $sess = $this->_container->get("session"); // Get the current session

        $user = $this->_container->get('security.context')->getToken(); // CHANGE IS HERE

        dump($user); 
    }
}
```

Then there is no problem, tokens dumped to output fine and definitely exists and the page formatting is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that your not  logged in so you cannot get the user from a null object or try to pass  securityContext directly in the construct
take a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179191/constructor-in-symfony2-controller

Comment: Definitely logged, as mentioned before the getToken() dump works and returns a User (me).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the documentation of the function [`getToken()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/SecurityContext.html#method_getToken), you'll see that it returns `NULL` when the security context has no authentication token.

If that is the case and you try to access the method `getUser()` of `NULL`, the exception is thrown. That would explain why your first piece of code is failing and the second is not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? The getToken() method != NULL when used by itself, why would it become NULL after invoking getUser() on it?

Comment: No, when you call `$this->_container->get('security.context')->getToken()` it might be returning `NULL`. This doesn't throw an error, but if you do `$this->_container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()` what you might be doing is `NULL->getUser()` if `$this->_container->get('security.context')->getToken()` is returning NULL and that does throw an error.

Comment: As mentioned before I can tell by the dump that NULL is definitely not being returned...

Comment: I'd suggest making a simple if statement and be sure that that's the case in the first piece of code. I might be wrong of course

Comment: 10000% sure that the token is != NULL, just did the if to check.

Comment: ok, thanks for checking that. Worth the try. Are you accessing a route that is behind the firewall? This error is usually thrown when the route to the action is not behind the firewall.

Comment: got     `firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false`

so i don't think so

Comment: Then make this test before getting the user 
 if ($securityContext->getToken() && is_object($securityContext->getToken()->getUser())){ 
....
}

Comment: what route are you accessing to make the tests? is that route behind the firewall? I'm not talking about the profiler, I'm talking about the route you're trying (it has to be behind a firewall to allow Symfony to populate the token)

Comment: Hajri, test returns true.

Comment: not sure what you mean by what route I'm accessing, all these tests take place on a local server if that helps

Comment: have you set up a firewall in your application? how did you log in? which routes are behind the firewall? If you are not behind a firewall, or if you run your logic before the authentication is completed by the security layer, the token should be null

Comment: That is really not the problem here, I have the same problem and my route is behind a firewall and everything. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue within my Symfony 4 application. My explanation is, that at the moment, your Listener gets called, the Token is not initialized and thus null, so calling anything on it throws an error. Maybe the `dump()`-function calls it later, when the Token is ready and contains a User, so dumping only the Token works? I don't know.

Nevertheless, I could resolve this by using the new (and not yet documented) `kernel.controller_arguments` (or `KernelEvents::CONTROLLER_ARGUMENTS`) event. There, the Token is initialized, contains a User and as a bonus, its `FilterControllerArgeumentsEvent` contains all the resolved arguments.

So have a look at `php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher` and see, where your Listener gets called and what is called before and later.